# Easy way to see if DataView is empty?

Tags: google-visualization, dataview

Using the Google visualization api, is there an easy way to see if a DataView is empty?

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView

I can see perhaps using dataView.getValue(0, 1) etc to check for nulls, but it also contains column headings.

I'm guessing it's tricky as the dataview could have many different formats, but is there a good generic way of checking for empty data views? I'm using the dataview for a pie chart.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, this can be easily done this way

```
var predata = response.getDataTable();
var vals = new Array();
var rownum = predata.getNumberOfRows();
// Make sure our data isn't empty.
if (null==predata) // yoda was here
return;
```

> Returns the data table as returned by the data source. Returns null if
>   the query execution failed and no data was returned.

Comment: Thanks Najzero, it might just be because my data table still has data contained within it, but it's null. It might just that my data is constructed oddly. I'm generating my data serverside using a record set, so if the rows have no data a null is inserted. Perhaps my case is an edge case, so why I'm finding it difficult to use the API with it.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the documentation, it seems like `dataView.getNumberOfRows()` is what you're looking for.  Before calling that, however, you need to get the filtered rows which are null and then hide them.  Here is [an example](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#another_data_view) using the Google Code Playground where I am checking one column for null and then hiding the row if it is null.  Replace Google Code's default JavaScript for that example with what's below:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name',   'Age', 'Instrument', 'Color'],
    [null,   null,     null,    null],
    ['Paul',   52,     'Sitar',     'Red'],
    ['George', 16,     'Guitar',    'Green'],
    ['Ringo',  72,     'Drums',     'White']
  ]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
  table.draw(dataTable, null);

  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);

  // Get rows where the 2nd column contains null
  var filteredRows = dataView.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value:null}]); 
  console.log(filteredRows);

  dataView.setColumns([0, 1]);

  // Hide the filtered rows returned
  dataView.hideRows(filteredRows);

  // Check the number of rows that now exist
  console.log(dataView.getNumberOfRows());

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(dataView, {width: 400, height: 200});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I've tried that to no avail, as it'll still return the number of rows even if the rows are empty. It might just be the way I'm constructing my datatable json server-side.

Comment: @Alex Key I've updated my answer with an example that may work for you.  I think you need to first use getFilteredRows to check for null and then hide the rows that are null.

Answer (score 1):

[getDistinctValues](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getDistinctValues) may help you with that. It works fine for line charts, when applied to columns which are visualized along Y-axis.

Comment: Thanks, I've +1 your answer but must admit my question was from a previous life in 2013 so wouldn't be able to test it out. But thanks for your help. I'll let a moderator mark it as the answer if it proves fruitful for others!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem quite right...

Perhaps I should replace null with 0 on the server-side before the client side even sees the data....

I've resorted to:

```
if (dataView.getValue(0, 1) === null || dataView.getValue(1, 1) === null || dataView.getValue(2, 1)) === null)
```

Where my dataview strucuture is:

```
Column Title 1 | Data
Column Title 2 | Data
Column Title 3 | Data
```

Comment: `null` usually means 'no data', while 0 (zero) is a valid numeric value (meaningful in most cases), so replacing `null` with 0 (zero) isn't an acceptable option in a common scenario...